Father and Son treasure hunters that ends with finding one last shipwreck (childrens/young adult)
Looking for a book that I read in school (mid 1990's, USA), so likely published in the 1980s or early 1990s. It was about a father and son treasure hunting team mainly looking for shipwrecks. The lived in the American South, most likely Florida.
The story starts with family doing well having recently found a large shipwreck. Over the years though, finds become increasingly rare and smaller returns. They may have been looking for a specific ship that hasn't been found but should technically still be out there based on historical records and legend. Toward the end they are left with almost nothing, but as luck would have they discover the ship they had been hunting for on the last tank of air they can afford.
For some reason a detail that sticks out to me is the son would gauge the status of the money the father had based on the condition of his "tennis shoes". This stuck out to me because as kid it was first exposure to running shoes being called "tennis shoes" instead of "sneakers".
I know it was a single book and is not the Treasure Hunters series by James Patterson, however, my search engine seems convinced it is...

Possibly Beyond the Reef by Todd Strasser


Life hasn't been easy for Chris in the five years since his parents moved to Key West and he and his father became treasure divers. Over the years they've made some startling finds: a seventeenth-century anchor and silver coins from a Spanish galleon.
But these early promises of an even greater cargo of Spanish gold have petered out, forcing Chris and his father to travel to Spain, to the Archives of the Indies in Seville. Perhaps more research will reveal clues to the lost ship. A year of deciphering the dusty records of a fabled era at last yields the final clue -- they are sure -- to the whereabouts of the treasure galleon.
Now the money and the credit have run out. Chris's mother is up north working, and he and his father are reduced to living on a derelct sailboat, scrounging for food, still in thrall to the silent lure of sunken gold.

The state of his tennis shoes is used as a barometer of his family's prosperity.

After eating two burgers I cleaned off a spot at the table and tried to get back to my homework. But it was hard to concentrate. I could hear my parents in the bedroom, no longer shouting, but talking as if they were trying to work things out. What Mom had said before about cooking dinner seemed to come straight out of left field, but the more I thought about it, the more it made sense. It wasn’t the hole in my tennis shoe that upset her as much as what it represented. Up north I’d never had holes in my sneakers, Dad had never brought greasy engine parts into the house, and Mom never had to sit around all day with nothing to do except wait for us to come home.

And they do indeed finally find the ship. The initial discovery is offscreen from the boy's perspective (he's working on his schooling since it looks like the treasure hunting won't pan out), but he winds up being the one who finds the treasure chest.
Currently, you can borrow a copy from the Internet Archive.
Found with a search for site:goodreads.com father and son scuba treasure hunters

Good find. And there was me thinking I was being clever by doing exact searches for the phrase "his tennis shoes" ...

@Randal'Thor: :-P I omitted the half dozen other search terms I tried first, including "tennis shoes". Apparently, the Goodreads reviewers didn't feel like mentioning his shoes.

I was searching Google Books and archive.org rather than Goodreads, hence hoping for an exact phrase from the text if not from reviews :-)

@Randal'Thor: It does find a few mentions on Google Books but yeah, similar searches aren't turning up much.

Why did I not think to use my own namesake as search term!?

I figured that you were discussing the last tank of air...
